# Call to a member function query() on null with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just checked all of the answers are available on stackoverflow,they are similar but not my answer exactly. So please don't take this post as duplicate.

these are my codes when I'm executing it say's

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in
>   C:\wamp64\www\ourCMS\index.php on line 12

Here is my snippet :

```
<?php

class DB
{
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbName;
    private $dbUser;
    private $dbPass;

    protected $con;

    function set_db($host, $db, $user, $pass)
    {
        $this->dbHost = $host;
        $this->dbName = $db;
        $this->dbUser = $user;
        $this->dbPass = $pass;

    }

    function connect()
    {
        $info = 'mysql:host='.$this->dbHost.';dbname='.$this->dbName;
        try
        {
            $this->con = new PDO($info, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            print "Error Founds: ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
            die();
        }
    }
}

// here is the place where i'm trying to use this actually
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include('include/database.php');

    $database = new DB;
    $database->set_db("localhost", "ourcms", "root", "");
    $conn = $database->connect();

    $name = $_POST['nm'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO testingpdo (name) VALUES ('$name')";
    $data = $conn->query($query);
    $result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    print_r($result);
}
```

Comment: There are possibly hundreds of the same questions on Stack Oveflow and they 're answered. Really none of them didn't help you to solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah really ! I just checked maximum of them but they didn't workout on me !

Comment: That's weird because all of them are about the same problem - you have a variable which contains a `null` value, but you're trying to use it as an object. The same as your problem. It rather looks to me, that you just copy&pasted that code from somewhere and you have no clue what is it doing.

Comment: No Man it's not like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return nothing from DB::connect (`$conn = $database->connect();`). Add `return $this->con;` at the end of the function.

```
function connect()
{
    $info = 'mysql:host='.$this->dbHost.';dbname='.$this->dbName;
    try
    {
        $this->con = new PDO($info, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        print "Error Founds: ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
        die();
    }
    return $this->con;
}
```

Comment: Oh ~~~~~ Is that was the only problem ? Yeah it is ! Thank you man !